# Python TypeError: Find_Number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limitdivision'

Tags: python, python-3.x

TypeError: Find_Number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limitdivision'
I still not get why my code is error:

```
def main():
    obj = FindMaxNumber()
    result = obj.Final_Result(500)
    print("The Final Result is {} ". format(result))

class FindMaxNumber():
    delf Find_Division(self, num):  
        self.num = num      
        if num%2==0:
            num = num/2
            count = 0
            division = 1
            while num%2==0:
                 count+=1
                 num = num/2
            division=division*( count + 1 )
            div = 3
            while num != 1:
                count = 0
                while num%div==0:
                        count+=1
                        num = num/div
                division = division( count + 1)
                div+=2
        return division
    def Find_Number(self, limitdivision):
        self.limitdivision = limitdivision 
        n = 1
        inum , fnum = FindMaxNumber.Find_Division(n) , FindMaxNumber.Find_Division(n+1)
        while inum*fnum < limitdivision:
            n+=1
            inum , fnum = fnum , FindMaxNumber.Find_Division(n+1)
        return inum
    def Final_Result(self , index):
        self.index = index
        num = FindMaxNumber.Find_Number(index)
        final = (num(num+1)/2)
        return final
if __name__=="__main__": main()
```

Can anyone tell what I support to do with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the method *on the class*. You probably wanted to call it on `self` instead:

```
num = self.Find_Number(index)
```

This goes for all `FindMaxNumber.` references in your methods; call methods on the instance unless you have a very specific reason to call them on the class instead, in which case you need to pass in an instance as the first argument, explicitly.

Comment: Can you explain to me more clearly for your comment that "you need to pass in an instance as the first argument".

Comment: @Makara: By accessing methods on the class, you are accessing an *unbound* method (Python 2) or the function (Python 3) directly, and no instance is bound. You need to explicitly pass in an object for the `self` parameter of those methods. By accessing the method on the *instance* (so via `self`) the method is bound and the `self` parameter is filled in for you by Python.