# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_size'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, typeerror, self

Hi I'm facing the below error. Please let me know how to go about it.

I'm facing error related to arguments in `model.add(TimeDistributedDense(self.output_size))`

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from keras.preprocessing import sequence
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers.core import Activation, RepeatVector, TimeDistributedDense, Dropout, Dense
    from keras.layers import recurrent
    from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
    import numpy as np
    from preprocessing import preprocess
    import pdb
    RNN = recurrent.LSTM


    class seq2seq(object):
    # Initialize model parameters
        def __init__(self, input_size, seqlen, output_size, input_dim = 100, \
             hidden_dim = 200):
            self.maxlen = seqlen
            self.input_size = input_size
            self.output_size = output_size
            self.input_dim = input_dim
            self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        def seq2seq_plain(self):
        # Plain seq2seq
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Embedding(self.input_size , self.input_dim))
            model.add(RNN(self.hidden_dim, return_sequences=True))#, input_shape=(100, 128)))

            model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(RNN(self.hidden_dim))
            model.add(RepeatVector(self.maxlen))
            #model.add(RNN(self.hidden_dim, return_sequences=True))
            #model.add(Dropout(0.25))
            model.add(RNN(self.hidden_dim, return_sequences=True))
            model.add(TimeDistributedDense(self.output_size))
            model.add(Dropout(0.5))
            model.add(Activation('softmax'))

            model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
            return model

       def seq2seq_attention(self):
            raise NotImplementedError


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test the model 
    seq2seq = seq2seq(15, 5500)
    seq2seq.train_seq2seq()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<ipython-input-36-392427814c8f>", line 50, in <module>
     seq2seq = seq2seq(15, 5500)

     TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_size'
```

Comment: You're using the same name for the class and for the object. You're overriding your class doing that.

Comment: The constructor for `seq2seq` requires three arguments, you are only supplying two (the first, `self`, is a reference to the current object).  Either supply a third argument or give a default for `output_size`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: Find\_Number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limitdivision'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022428/python-typeerror-find-number-missing-1-required-positional-argument-limitdi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, input_size, seqlen, output_size, input_dim = 100, hidden_dim = 200)
```

It means you have to at least pass values of `input_size`, `seqlen` and `output_size`, i.e you have to pass 3 parameters. Other parameters like `input_dim` and `hidden_dim` have default values, so you don't have to provide values for them while creating the object. But you have to pass **3** parameters while creating object.

You are currently creating the object by passing **only 2** parameters.

```
 seq2seq = seq2seq(15, 5500)
```

Change it by giving **1 more** parameter for `output_size` as it does not have any default value.

**Modify:**

1. *Pass 1 more parameter for output_size*
2. *Object name should be different from class name*.

**Result:**

```
seq2seq_obj = seq2seq(15, 5500, 10) # 1 more parameter for output_size
```

Comment: Nicely Explained HarSha!